# How to cut a substring between 2 different characters of a string using a bash command?

Tags: bash, cut

I have the following string and I want to cut a substring out from between the first `-` and the `.`

```
something-123_2523123_1232+12312-more-GI2342.txt
```

I tried using the [cut](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-cut-command/) command like below:

```
echo something-123_2523123_1232+12312-more-GI2342.txt | cut -d'-' -f 2
```

Output from above is `123_2523123_1232+12312` which is half correct. The `cut` command has picked  up the first `-` correctly but then I need to tell it to continue until the `.` and output the substring. How do I do this?

Or how do I cut out a substring between the first `-` and the `.`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use two consecutive `cut`. With `-f2-` you can select all fields starting at the second field.

```
echo something-123_2523123_1232+12312-more-GI2342.txt | cut -d- -f2- | cut -d. -f1
```

Alternatively, use bash's built-in [parameter expansion](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal).

```
s=something-123_2523123_1232+12312-more-GI2342.txt
s=${s#*-}
s=${s%%.*}
echo "$s"
```

<sub>... or `sed` or `grep`. There are many more ways to do this.</sub>